# Delphi - Erro em comparação de datas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Fiz uma comparação entre duas datas.
Quando a variável 'data' contém a data de HOJE, o código entende que ela é menor

```
if data < now then

  begin

  ...//se a variável DATA fosse igual a hoje (now), ele iria executar esse comando como se DATA fosse menor que NOW

  end;
```

Comment: Ele não está trazendo a data completa (dd:mm:aaaa hh:mm:ss) ? Dependendo o que foi gravado, ele vai entender que é menor. O bom seria truncar a váriavel na comparação...

Comment: também acho que seja isso (hh:mm:ss), como faço pra "truncar"?

Comment: Trunc(SeuCampoDateTime)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760929/how-to-encode-a-datetime-in-delphi

Comment: Deu certo usando o Trunc, obrigado ^^

Aproveito pra perguntar onde que eu confirmo que já resolvi minha pergunta.

Comment: Vou responder ela e vc aceita a resposta dai. Fica registrado para alguem que também tenha essa duvida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possivelmente está havendo "confusão" no `now`, que contém hora/minuto/segundo e no campo armanezado pode estar outro valor qualquer. Para resolver, pode usar o comando `trunc`:

```
if trunc(data) < trunc(now) then
```

Dessa forma deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez